# What is a typical use-case for PersistentView in Akka?

Tags: akka, system.reactive, akka-stream, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

Here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence.html is written:

> PersistentView: A view is a persistent, stateful actor that receives
>   journaled messages that have been written by another persistent actor.
>   A view itself does not journal new messages, instead, it updates
>   internal state only from a persistent actor's replicated message
>   stream.

What is a typical use-case for PersistentView ?

How is it different from [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html#stream-quickstart-scala) / RX?

It looks pretty similar to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it useful if you're designing your application based on [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). *CQRS fits well with event-sourced* systems as can be seen in the blog post.

While you might use `PersistentActor` actors to update the state of your application - this is the command side / model, `PersistentView` actors come in handy when you want to display the data, so on the query side.

An example would be storing data about bank accounts. In a traditional model you would probably have all CRUD operations under some repository. A really basic transformation in this model would be to use the `PersistentActor` for the CUD bit and `PersistentView` for the R bit. The nice thing is that you decouple the command part which updates the state from the query side.

As for the last question, `akka-persistence` and `akka-streams` are made for different purposes. As a matter of fact `akka-persistence-query-experimental` actually is built using `akka-streams` to provide different sources. An example is actually [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence-query.html#Read_Journals). Note that `PersistentView` is deprecated in the latest version and it's recommended to use `PersistenceQuery`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)